# Relation between two asymptotics

Tags: asymptotics

What is is the largest $0<c<4$ that satisfies
$$2^{n + \sqrt{n}} \in O((4-c)^n)$$
?

Comment: Are you looking for the minimum $c>0$ for which this stops being true? (also, your inclusion is strange. It should be either $\in$ or, with a slight abuse of notation, $=$.)

Comment: @ClementC. Ya I had the left side defined asymptotically originally, hence the subset notation, but then I edited and forgot to change it to \in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any fixed $c\in(-\infty, 4)$, we have
$$
\frac{2^{n+\sqrt{n}}}{(4-c)^n} = 2^{n+\sqrt{n} - n\log_2 (4-c)} = 2^{(1-\log_2 (4-c))n + \sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \begin{cases}
\infty & \text{ if } 1-\log_2 (4-c) \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{ if } 1-\log_2 (4-c) < 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
so for your satement to hold, you need (and it is sufficient) $1-\log_2 (4-c) < 0$, or equivalently $c < 2$.